# Using terraform to deploy a Spring boot azurerm_app_service with upload of jar

Tags: azure, spring-boot, azure-web-app-service, terraform

I have been attempting this for a good chunk of today but still have not found a solution.

1. I have a built spring boot application in the form of a jar.
2. I push this to a storage account container as a blob with azurerm_storage_blob
3. I reference this from a azurerm_app_service in app_settings.WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE using a data.azurerm_storage_account_sas
4. I see that it has pulled the blob from storage in the app-service but it has exploded it under D:\home\site\wwwroot
5. I have set site_config.java* (java_version, java_container and java_container_version) but it makes no attempt to start the application

I see there is a site_config.app_command_line but none of the examples I have found set this.

Has anybody gotten a spring boot application in a windows app service running using terraform?
Is there a better way to get the application jar to azure using terraform?

Comment: Would be interested to know what the 2 downvotes were for?

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to deploy your application to Azure App Service. For your scenario,  I recommend not to set WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE and make sure your executable jar is called **app.jar** and it is dropped to the root of your Web App's content folder (/site/wwwroot).

App Service will automatically take care of setting the appropriate SERVER_PORT environment variable behind the scenes, so that when your Spring Boot application starts, it will start listening to the correct port.

If you need to set parameters, you can always set JAVA_OPTS in the App Service Settings section in the Azure portal and those will travel as environment variables and ultimately used by java.exe upon start.

If you hit any rough edge, feel free to open a ticket in Azure portal and we will be able to assist you better to make sure your app runs well in Azure App Service.

Other popular mechanism to deploy is using Maven:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/java/spring-framework/deploy-spring-boot-java-app-with-maven-plugin

Comment: Thanks for the answer. "make sure your executable jar is called app.jar and it is dropped to the root of your Web App's content folder (/site/wwwroot)". We are trying to deploy this via terraform: how do I get my app.jar into the web app using terraform?